# Multiple linked artifacts in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, continuous-delivery

I've configured Release Pipeline with two artifacts linked to it and each artifacts has set to create release whenever new build is available. These two artifact come from two different modules on separate GIT repo's.

[image]

In this case, release pipeline will get triggered twice(one per artifact). But I wanted it to get triggered only after all the linked artifact builds are succeeded. Tried finding solution in the docs, but couldn't find it much helpful. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is not possible to trigger a release only after all the linked artifact builds are succeeded. Azure devops doesnot have such a feature to configure this yet. A new release will now be triggered when either of the linked artifacts build is succeeded.

You will have to create two different release pipelines, one for each artifact.  Or you will have to find a way to put BuildA and BuildB in one artifact.

You can [submit a feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) to Microsoft Development team. Hope they will consider implementing this feature in the future sprint. Or you can vote on [this existing user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/987864/continuous-deployment-with-multiple-artifacts.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to configure it out of the box. It will trigger release just after one of artifact become available. If you want to overcome this, you need to create some custom app to monitor artifacts and trigger release once both artifacts meet some condition.

[There is topic in developer community to implement this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/987864/continuous-deployment-with-multiple-artifacts.html).